# NodeSeqMarshaller with ContentType charset not resolving

Tags: scala, character-encoding, marshalling, spray

Attempting to get a spray endpoint negotiating a postman request for content. My XML marshaller seems to let me down, ie, it never resolves the correct marshaller option based on Accept header and charset.

I have the following:

```
object ResponseVO {  
   val NodeSeqMarshaller = Marshaller.delegate[ResponseVO, NodeSeq](ContentType(`text/xml`, `UTF-8`)) { respVO => <ussd><type>{ respVO.respType }</type><message>{ respVO.message }</message></ussd> }

   val supportedContentTypes = List[ContentType](ContentType(`text/xml`, `UTF-8`))
   implicit val marshaller = Marshaller[ResponseVO] { (respVO, ctx) =>
   ctx.tryAccept(supportedContentTypes) match {
    case Some(ContentType(`text/xml`, `UTF-8`)) => NodeSeqMarshaller(respVO, ctx)
    case whatever                               => println(whatever); ctx.rejectMarshalling(supportedContentTypes);
  }
}
}
```

and the following route:

```
trait USSDRoute { 
  this: SimpleRoutingApp with BootStrappedActorSystem  =>
  val ussdRoute = path("ussd") {
                  parameters('msisdn.as[Long], 'session.as[String], 'type.as[Int], 'msg.as[String], 'network.as[Int]) { (msisdn, session, reqType, msg, network) =>
        complete {
          val reqVO = RequestVO(msisdn, session, reqType, msg, network)
          println(s"received $reqVO")
          ResponseVO(1, "Spirit midget medium escapes from prison, headlines read: Small medium at large!")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately I never seem to negotiate correctly, ie, my marshaller resolution will dive bomb into the "whatever" block and respond with a 406

```
"Resource representation is only available with these Content-Types:
```

text/xml; charset=UTF-8"

I am using Postman and my request headers read:

```
GET /ussd?msisdn=0794138690&type=1&network=4&msg=hello&session=99 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9999
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
```

It's probably something small and silly - hopefully someone can help steer me in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at how the case class `ContentType` is defined:

```
case class ContentType(mediaType: MediaType, definedCharset: Option[HttpCharset])
```

Note that `definedCharset` is defined as an `Option[HttpCharset]`, therefore your pattern match via

```
case Some(ContentType(`text/xml`, `UTF-8`)) => ...
```

never can succeed. So you need to use a `Some` to perform the pattern match successfully:

```
case Some(ContentType(`text/xml`, Some(`UTF-8`))) => ...
```